# ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, pika, amazon-mq

Hy, I'm created a AmazonMQ using broker as RabbitMQ. Now I want to publish a message and read that message from the queue using python. So I followed the steps given in the AWS docs.

[Link: Using Python Pika with Amazon MQ for RabbitMQ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-rabbitmq-pika.html#amazon-mq-rabbitmq-pika-publisher-basic-publish)

I follow the same steps in docs but when I tried to send a message to the queue it gives me this error!

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:/Axcer/Using-Python-Pika-with-Amazon-MQ-for-RabbitMQ/publisher.py", line 26, in 
> basic_message_sender = BasicMessageSender(
>
> File "E:\Axcer\Using-Python-Pika-with-Amazon-MQ-for-RabbitMQ\basicClient.py", line 15, in **init**
> parameters = pika.URLParameters(url)
>
> File "E:\Axcer\Using-Python-Pika-with-Amazon-MQ-for-RabbitMQ\Intern\lib\site-packages\pika\connection.py", line 757, in **init**
> if parts.port is not None:
>
> File "C:\Users\Yomal\Python38-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 174, in port
> raise ValueError(message) from None
> ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as 'xxxxxyyyy'

I have really no Idea about this issue! I hope that someone can help me with this. Thank you!

basicClient.py

```
import ssl
import pika

class BasicPikaClient:

    def __init__(self, rabbitmq_broker_id, rabbitmq_user, rabbitmq_password, region):

        # SSL Context for TLS configuration of Amazon MQ for RabbitMQ
        ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
        ssl_context.set_ciphers('ECDHE+AESGCM:!ECDSA')

        url = f"amqps://{rabbitmq_user}:{rabbitmq_password}@{rabbitmq_broker_id}.mq.{region}.amazonaws.com:5671"
        parameters = pika.URLParameters(url)
        parameters.ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(context=ssl_context)

        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
```

publisher.py

```
from basicClient import BasicPikaClient

class BasicMessageSender(BasicPikaClient):

    def declare_queue(self, queue_name):
        print(f"Trying to declare queue({queue_name})...")
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name)

    def send_message(self, exchange, routing_key, body):
        channel = self.connection.channel()
        channel.basic_publish(exchange=exchange,
                              routing_key=routing_key,
                              body=body)
        print(f"Sent message. Exchange: {exchange}, Routing Key: {routing_key}, Body: {body}")

    def close(self):
        self.channel.close()
        self.connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Initialize Basic Message Sender which creates a connection
    # and channel for sending messages.
    basic_message_sender = BasicMessageSender(
        "*******************",
        "xxxxx",
        "xxxxxyyyy#zzzzzzz",
        "********"
    )

    # Declare a queue
    basic_message_sender.declare_queue("hello world queue")

    # Send a message to the queue.
    basic_message_sender.send_message(exchange="", routing_key="hello world queue", body=b'Hello World!')

    # Close connections.
    basic_message_sender.close()
```

Comment: This error could happen if the URL contains one or more special characters. 
Maybe your user or password contains one of these characters: '/', '?', '#', '@', ':'
Can you try changing it (user or psw) to discard this problem?